# Variable function names

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on a plugin that will add messages to a WooCommerce product at set places on a single item/product page and run into an issue that to be honest I have never needed a requirement for in the past.

The issue is variable function names.

What I want to be able to do is add multiple messages at key places in a product page, while I am able to target the places I want from a custom post type via a select options box I dont know how many messages in the page someone might want to add and with only one function name this is going to cause errors such as already declared if multiple messages are added for one product.

Is there a way to generate or use 'variable_function' names in a PHP function? I have tried a few ways all have not worked and even the mighty Google has failed to help me with a work around or way to allow for this to be done.

Take the below for an example I can call this once.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'variable_function', 15 );

function variable_function() {
echo 'this is the first message';
}
```

But what if i wanted to call the below also to add a second message at a different location I will get the error already declared on line ---,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'variable_function', 15 );

function variable_function() {
echo 'This is a second message';
}
```

without adding a single option for all possible areas this leaves me only able to add one message per single product and to add single options means the plugin will be bloated and not versatile.

So is there way to random generate functions name such as

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'variable_function'.$randomn_info, 15 );

    function variable_function.$randomn_info() {
    echo 'this is the first message';
    }
```

Or am I missing something very obvious?

I appreciate any help you might be able to give!

Thanks....

Comment: I don't understand why variable function names would be needed. How are these messages stored and retrieved?

Comment: I am using a custom post type to create a post with the messages, I loop over the post type and check if the current page viewed has the product id in any of the posts and if it does triggers the add_action function. Issue is I can have different areas on the product page that messages can go and I have tried to call remove_action but this did not work.